# Grafana / Dell PowerFlex Block Size Display in Dashboard

Tags: grafana

Has anyone created a dashboard for Dell PowerFlex that shows the block size for workloads? PowerFlex manager has the ability to report and show block sizes so can this data be queried by Grafana? Thanks!

Current dashboard layout

[image: 1]

Comment: What is the data source here, and how does it get it's data for "Dell PowerFlex"? If your data source has metric for your "block size for workloads" you should be able to add a panel without problem. If not - Grafana can't visualise something that is missing.